# Is there a way to write the Eclipse filesearch (Ctrl + H) in code?

Tags: java, eclipse, methods, file-search

I am currently trying to search the whole project for different strings. The best way to do this manually is the built-in Eclipse function "fileSearch". Is there a way to write a method in Java that does exactly the same thing so it searches every file for a given string and then returns true or false when it finds something?

Thanks for your help,

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is possible. You can implement a tree walker as explained in the [Java Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/walk.html). For every file encountered, the content of the file would be read and checked for an occurrence of the searched for string.

Depending on the result you want to achieve, you could stop the tree walk as soon as at least one matching file is found, or you could collect the paths of all matching files, or ...

Comment: Wow. Thank you I will try that!